# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: Wireless connection issue while on external HDMI-Monitor

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I sometimes have network issues (no signal, slow upload, etc.) and I think I finally can reproduce them:
I noticed a strange behavior between my wifi and my external HDMI port / monitor.

**Configuration with issues:**

- external monitor plugged into HDMI-port on laptop and monitor turned on.

**Configurations without issues:**

- external monitor plugged into HDMI-port on laptop and monitor turned off.
- external monitor plugged into HDMI-dongle and monitor turned on.
- external monitor not plugged in (only internal monitor)

The issues start and stop as soon as I change the configuration - like: immediately, tested with an upload-speedtester.

Honestly I can't imagine what could cause this behavior. Fortunately for me I can still work with my usb-c to HDMI dongle flawlessly, but it would still be good to see this fixed.
(if I don't "see ghosts")

**Operating system:**

```
uname -a
Linux HP-x360 5.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 23:42:32 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Computermodel:**
HP HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15-ee0xxx

**Networking hardware:**

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlo1
       Version: 00
       Seriennummer: 20:4e:f6:f2:35:2b
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=5.15.0-39-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.168 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:79 ioport:2000(Größe=256) memory:d0700000-d070ffff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Physische ID: e
       Bus-Informationen: usb@2:1.1
       Logischer Name: enx00e04c68503a
       Seriennummer: 00:e0:4c:68:50:3a
       Größe: 10Mbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Fähigkeiten: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.12 duplex=half firmware=rtl8153b-2 v1 10/23/19 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

edit 1: upload speedtest (testmy.net) added:
three uploads then HDMI port change, repeated three times

| Configuration | Upload speed [MBit/s] |
| --- | --- |
| HDMI-adapter | 5.0 |
| HDMI-adapter | 5.0 |
| HDMI-adapter | 5.6 |
| HDMI-port | timeout |
| HDMI-port | 1.4 |
| HDMI-port | 0.3 |
| HDMI-adapter | 4.6 |
| HDMI-adapter | 5.0 |
| HDMI-adapter | 5.7 |
| HDMI-port | 0.4 |
| HDMI-port | 2.5 |
| HDMI-port | 2.0 |
| HDMI-adapter | 5.3 |
| HDMI-adapter | 4.2 |
| HDMI-adapter | 5.7 |
| HDMI-port | 2.8 |
| HDMI-port | 1.6 |
| HDMI-port | 2.3 |

edit 2: output from NetworkManager added
as expected there are no additional entries after startup

```
sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.5427] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.5431] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.c>
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.5462] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.5525] manager[0x55db6c2c3040]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.5525] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7772] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7772] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "HP-x360"
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7778] dns-mgr[0x55db6c2a02a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7790] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver rtw_88>
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7792] manager[0x55db6c2c3040]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7792] manager[0x55db6c2c3040]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7815] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7829] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7860] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7874] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7882] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7885] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7886] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7886] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7898] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7898] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7899] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7900] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7976] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7977] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7979] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7987] manager: (enx00e04c68503a): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7995] settings: (enx00e04c68503a): created default wired connection 'Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1'
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.7995] device (enx00e04c68503a): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.8140] device (wlo1): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.8144] manager: (wlo1): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jun 23 19:42:12 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006132.8149] device (wlo1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.7587] manager: (virbr0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.7598] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.7676] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8030] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8031] device (wlo1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8555] device (virbr0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8557] device (virbr0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8561] device (virbr0): Activation: starting connection 'virbr0' (ee363bf8-2bf6-43c0-91e3-b9a52d528f6c)
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8562] device (virbr0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8563] device (virbr0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8564] device (virbr0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8565] device (virbr0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8601] device (virbr0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8602] device (virbr0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8604] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 23 19:42:13 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006133.8605] device (virbr0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 23 19:42:15 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006135.0808] agent-manager: agent[3a62a9a74f1147cf,:1.42/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9344] policy: auto-activating connection '3WebGate' (f8d42f10-7f37-4e7c-9fc9-771b7c5f5551)
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9349] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection '3WebGate' (f8d42f10-7f37-4e7c-9fc9-771b7c5f5551)
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9350] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9352] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9355] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9358] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point '3WebGate' has security, but secrets are required.
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9358] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9359] sup-iface[1ace2d2b57d497d5,0,wlo1]: wps: type pbc start...
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9369] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9372] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9374] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection '3WebGate' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9374] Config: added 'ssid' value '3WebGate'
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9375] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9375] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9375] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9375] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jun 23 19:42:17 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006137.9375] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jun 23 19:42:18 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006138.4428] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Jun 23 19:42:18 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006138.4634] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jun 23 19:42:18 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006138.5075] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jun 23 19:42:18 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006138.5323] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Jun 23 19:42:18 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006138.5869] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jun 23 19:42:18 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006138.5869] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "3WebGate"
Jun 23 19:42:18 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006138.5870] device (wlo1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:18 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006138.5915] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.2459] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed new lease, address=192.168.2.168
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.2480] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.2523] device (wlo1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.2524] device (wlo1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.2525] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.2528] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.2528] policy: set 'xxx' (wlo1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.2532] device (wlo1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.2535] manager: startup complete
Jun 23 19:42:21 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006141.5681] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jun 23 19:42:23 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006143.5522] dhcp6 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 23 19:42:23 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006143.5531] policy: set 'xxx' (wlo1) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Jun 23 19:42:23 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656006143.5698] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed new lease
Jun 23 20:02:41 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656007361.6030] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 23 20:02:41 HP-x360 NetworkManager[1681]: <info>  [1656007361.8743] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

sudo journalctl -b 0  when changing HDMI port

```
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gsd-media-keys[2382]: Unable to get default sink
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Jun 23 20:16:29 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Jun 23 20:16:31 HP-x360 org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop[2420]: qt.qpa.wayland: Creating a fake screen in order for Qt not to crash
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 rtkit-daemon[1962]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 rtkit-daemon[1962]: Successfully made thread 13718 of process 1958 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 rtkit-daemon[1962]: Supervising 9 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Jun 23 20:16:32 HP-x360 gnome-shell[2059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Jun 23 20:16:38 HP-x360 sudo[13633]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 23 20:16:39 HP-x360 sudo[13719]:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b 0
Jun 23 20:16:39 HP-x360 sudo[13719]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: updated post with additional information

Answer (score 0):

not a complete answer, but I am facing the same issues. I tried to reduce the number of ports in use, but the problem seems to be the HDMI cable. Some people on the internet suggest upgrading to a better one, as low-quality cables might create interference. Also, I tried to change the kernel, and I noticed this problem emerged when I moved from 20.04 to 22.04.
I am currently on `5.15.0-53-generic` and it seems to be more stable compared to newer kernels.